# forming a sublist from lists

Tags: python-3.x, list, arraylist

I have 3 lists:

```
color = ['red','orange','purple','black']
number = ['2','4','6','77']
letter = ['K','R','U','Z']
```

what I want to end up with is:

```
mylist=[['K','R','U','Z','red','2'],['K','R','U','Z','orange','4'],['K','R','U','Z','purple','6'], ['K','R','U','Z','black','77']]
```

I tried:

```
for i in range(4):
    letter.append(color[i])
    letter.append(number[i])
```

This does not give me what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension for that :

```py
color = ['red','orange','purple','black']
number = ['2','4','6','77']
letter = ['K','R','U','Z']
mylist = [ letter + [c, n] for c, n in zip(color, number) ]
print(mylist)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not so beautiful but pretty simple in my opinion:

```
color = ['red', 'orange', 'purple', 'black']
number = ['2', '4', '6', '77']
letter = ['K', 'R', 'U', 'Z']

my_list = []
for i in range(len(color)):
    new_list = letter[:]
    my_list.append(new_list)
    new_list.append(color[i])
    new_list.append(number[i])

print(my_list)
```

Output:

```
[['K', 'R', 'U', 'Z', 'red', '2'], ['K', 'R', 'U', 'Z', 'orange', '4'], ['K', 'R', 'U', 'Z', 'purple', '6'], ['K', 'R', 'U', 'Z', 'black', '77']]
```